# unexpected behaviour with powers of 2

Tags: haskell

I found a strange error in some code I wrote for computing estimates based on binary logarithms (log base 2). Here is the code for `lb`, which computes the binary logarithm of a positive integer:

```
lb :: Int -> Maybe Int -- Binary logarithm, rounded down
lb 1 = Just 0
lb x
    | 1 < x = (+1) <$> lb (div x 2)
    | otherwise = Nothing
```

Here is the error, as demonstrated in the following annotated ghci output

```
λ: lb (2^30)
Just 30
λ: lb (2^31) -- should be Just 31
Nothing
λ: 1 < 2^31 -- smoke check, lb's first guard evaluates to True
True
λ: lb (div (2^31) 2) == lb (2^30) -- smoke check, these should be equal
False
λ: div (2^31) 2 == 2^30 -- smoke check, these are indeed equal
True
```

It seems that `lb (2^31)` somehow fails the first guard, leading to the `otherwise` expression, but I can find no consistent explanation for why.

Additionally, it seems the expression `div (2^31) 2` is somehow not evaluating to the same thing as `2^30` in the body of `lb`

Comment: Did you try switching `Int` to `Integer`? I think there is probably an underflow issue. And I think default is `Integer` so the third lambda should work...

Comment: Ah, I forgot to type-constrain the test values. Yep, that should solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch from `Int` to `Integer`. Basically, you are creating an `Int` so large that it overflows. `Integer` is arbitrary precision.

(Note: On different architectures, the number can vary. My computer fails at `63` instead of `31`).

Comment: I'm using Integral to keep it general, but that works well